# Application auto starting after reboot even though I don't want that

Tags: android

I have an app which is auto starting after reboot on some phones. On my S3 with 4.4.2 (Samsung rom) it does not, but on my Nexus 4 with 4.4.4 (Google stock rom) it does.

I do not have the broadcast receivers for bootup but I do have some broadcast receivers which I'm gonna paste below:

```
            <action android:name="android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"/>
            <action android:name="android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION"/>
            <action
                    android:name="toggleplayback"/>
            <action android:name="notification.stop"/>
```

And

```
            <action android:name="play"></action>
            <action android:name="pause"></action>
            <action android:name="stop"></action>
            <action android:name="forward"></action>
            <action android:name="back"></action>
            <action android:name="playtoggle"></action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"/>
```

Is the OS maybe sending a media button even on startup?

Thanks.

Comment: `android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY` is more likely to be the cause (as seen here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY) . Have you tried without it?

Comment: Interesting, I'll take a look and see if it is totally necessary, that line I have for some other library in my code.

Comment: Wow seems like you are totally right, thank you.